# Transform inherited object to specific key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have one object and inside the object, there have roles(array of number) and I want to transform only the roles, it should be an array of objects. see below

current object,

```
displayConfiguration: {
  widgetList: {
    widgetName: 'widget tiltle',
    entityType: 'Asset',
    roles: [202]
  },
  addIcon: {
    fileName: '',
    fileDownloadUri: ''
  },
  displayInfoIcon: {
    visible: true,
    summaryText: 'info icon text'
  },
  useFilter: true
}
```

expected object

```
displayConfiguration: {
  widgetList: {
    widgetName: 'widget tiltle',
    entityType: 'Asset',
    roles: [
      {
        id: 202
      }
    ]
  },
  addIcon: {
    fileName: '',
    fileDownloadUri: ''
  },
  displayInfoIcon: {
    visible: true,
    summaryText: 'info icon text'
  },
  useFilter: true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const displayConfiguration = {
  widgetList: {
    widgetName: 'widget tiltle',
    entityType: 'Asset',
    roles: [202]
  },
  addIcon: {
    fileName: '',
    fileDownloadUri: ''
  },
  displayInfoIcon: {
    visible: true,
    summaryText: 'info icon text'
  },
  useFilter: true
}

const answer = {
  ...displayConfiguration, 
  widgetList: {
    ...displayConfiguration.widgetList,
    roles: displayConfiguration.widgetList.roles.map(x => ({id: x}))
  }
  
}

console.log(answer)
```

Should be rather straight forward, you can use `map` function to transform array

Answer (score 1):

You can you use `.map()` function, that will walk through each element and convert your number to object that you need.

```js
const displayConfiguration = {
  widgetList: {
    widgetName: 'widget tiltle',
    entityType: 'Asset',
    roles: [202]
  },
  addIcon: {
    fileName: '',
    fileDownloadUri: ''
  },
  displayInfoIcon: {
    visible: true,
    summaryText: 'info icon text'
  },
  useFilter: true
};

const roles = displayConfiguration.widgetList.roles;
displayConfiguration.widgetList.roles = roles.map(role => {
 return {
  id: role
 }
})

console.log(displayConfiguration);
```

The [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.